# jquery run php function on same page then print window

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am beginner at jquery and ajax and have investigated all threads I can find on this subject also had a look at ajax tutorials but still have problem.
I have a jquery script that prints the current page in my Wordpress child theme and this works fine.

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#print-poem").click(function(){
                    window.print();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

```html
<button type="button" id="print-poem">PRINT</button>
```

When the button is clicked I also want to update a custom field in the Wordpress database on the same post that is being show when button is clicked. I want to enter "Printed" in the field.

I have tried creating a php function on the same page and adding ajax to the above script (also on same page) without success.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#print-poem").click(function(){
                   window.print();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'mark-printed',
     success: function(data) {
     alert('has function run');
       }
     });
         });
        });
</script>
```

```html
<button type="button" id="print-poem">PRINT</button>

<?php    
  function mark_printed () { 
        $transaction_status = 'Printed';
        $field_key = "field_58c7ce7357709";
        update_field( $field_key, $transaction_status, $post_id );
        }
?>
```

I have also tried puting the php in a stand alone file and entering the file url but thi didn't help either.

Can someone advise how to achieve printing the window and updating the database.

Comment: give the page extension in the URL 
change
`url: 'mark-printed'` .
To 
`url: 'mark-printed.php'`

Answer (score 0):

That's not how ajax+php works.

When you do this you have to keep two files, one for printing page and other is for updating database.

**your_ajax_file.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#print-poem").click(function(){
                   window.print();

                $.ajax({
                  url: 'your_php_file.php?post_id=' + post_id,//add your post id here
                  type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                       alert('has function run');
                    }
                    });
         });
        });
</script>
<button type="button" id="print-poem">PRINT</button>
```

**your_php_file.php**

```
<?php    
     function mark_printed ($post_id) { 
           $transaction_status = 'Printed';
           $field_key = "field_58c7ce7357709";
           update_field( $field_key, $transaction_status, 1 );
        }

     $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
     mark_printed($post_id);//you have to call the function and send post i that sent from ajax
?>
```